# Inline listing shows redundant items in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Let me show you an example:

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Author, Book


class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', ('date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')]
    inlines = [BookInline]
```

This configuration generates the following layout:

[image]

The problem is, this author has only written one book(i.e. `Book 009`), but I got four books listed out(i.e. `Book 009` and three "empty" books). Why is it? How can I disable this feature(or bug, whatever)?

[image]

Comment: Did the below answer worked for your case?

Comment: @nik_m Yes! Answer accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django admin adds additional rows in case you want to add values for each of them.

You can control how many [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) appear by setting the relevant attribute, like this:

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 1  # or extra = 0
```

There also other goodies for your inline controls like, [max_num](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num), [min_num](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.min_num) etc.